# Compare strings in excel vba

Tags: string, excel, vba

I have a bunch of strings comprising of characters "A","B"..."Z" (and no others). A typical string looks like `ABZYC`. The strings are given to me in pairs like `ABC`,`ABDC`. The strings are comparable if one string is contained in the other (i.e either one of the two strings contain all the alphabets of the other). The order in which the string appears don't matter.

Is there any direct function in excel vba which does this sort of comparison?

Examples:
`ACBD`,`AC` - `Match`
`ACBD`,`CA` - `Match`
`ACBD`,`ADB` - `Match`
`AC`,`ABCD` - `Match`
`ABC`, `ABD` - `No Match`

Comment: Does the order matter? In other words, does `ABCDEF` match `CB` or only `BC`? It was not completely apparent from your question. Maybe give some examples of things that do and don't match (by editing your question). Cheers.

Comment: you should ask this question on the [Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) forum - then we in the Excel-vba forum will help you include the answer in a VBA function

Comment: I checked, and RegEx may not be the way to go, it looks like you maye have to code a function to check each letter individually and return either Match or No Match for each of the strings

Comment: @hardikudeshi - please choose an answer or ask for clarification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following function in a module in your workbook:

```
Function allIn(str1, str2)
' check whether all elements of str1 occur in str2
' and vice versa
Dim l1, l2, ii As Integer
Dim isfound As Boolean

isfound = True

l1 = Len(str1)
l2 = Len(str2)

If l1 < l2 Then
' look for all the elements of str1 in str2
  For ii = 1 To l1
    If InStr(1, str2, Mid(str1, ii, 1), vbTextCompare) <= 0 Then
      isfound = False
      Exit For
    End If
  Next ii
Else
' look for all the elements of str2 in str1
  For ii = 1 To l2
    If InStr(1, str1, Mid(str2, ii, 1), vbTextCompare) <= 0 Then
      isfound = False
      Exit For
    End If
  Next ii
End If
allIn = isfound
End Function
```

Now you can call this from another place in your code, using `result = inStr("ABD", "BAD")` - or from the spreadsheet itself. On the spreadsheet you would type `=allIn(A3, B6)` to compare strings in cells `A3` and `B6`.

Here is what happens when I did that (I entered `=allIn(A1, B1)` in cell `C1`, then dragged the formula to the next four rows):

[image: screen shot of spreadsheet]

I believe that solves your problem.

EDIT: I just noticed @Philip's comment to your question - I appear to have implemented his suggestion although I had not seen it when I started to compose it... But here's a tip of the hat all the same!

Comment: I put mine into action whilst you were writing yours !

Answer (score 1):

INSTR will find a substring in a string:

```
Typical_String = "ABZYC"

if instr(Typical_String,"ABC") > 0 then
```

Comment: This won't help for strings like `ACBD`,`ADB`

Comment: Have you thought of using a [Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) or [RegEx Tutorial for Excel VBA](http://www.macrostash.com/2011/10/08/simple-regular-expression-tutorial-for-excel-vba/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a Formula solution, a user called *Schielrn* on the **Mr Excel** forum site came up with [this sublime masterpiece](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/690910-formula-compare-two-strings.html#post3417179) (using **ARRAY FORMULAS**)

Or, if you want a VBA, try this...

```
Sub compare()

Dim iIndx As Integer
Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String
Dim sLetter As String
Dim bFound As Boolean

Range("A1").Select
bFound = False

Do

    str1 = VBA.Trim(ActiveCell.Text)
    str2 = VBA.Trim(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Text)

    For iIndx = 1 To Len(str1)
        If VBA.InStr(str2, VBA.Mid(str1, iIndx, 1)) <> "" Then
            ' found it
            bFound = True
        Else
            bFound = False
            exit for
        End If
    Next

    If bFound = False Then
    ' check the other way!
        For iIndx = 1 To Len(str2)
            If VBA.InStr(str1, VBA.Mid(str2, iIndx, 1)) <> "" Then
                ' found it
                bFound = True
            Else
                bFound = False
            exit for
            End If
        Next
    End If

    If bFound = True Then ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "MATCHED!"

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop While Not ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Text = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: You can make it more efficient by breaking out of the `For` loop as soon as a character doesn't match... Also - it seems like your logic currently would allow a character in the middle not to match, as long as the last one is a match?

Comment: mmm, I think the formula solution from the Mr Excel website is the best answer Floris :)

Comment: I completely agree it's a very _clever_ solution; I disagree that it is the _best answer_: I wouldn't like to type that all over my spreadsheet. You have to enter the reference to the two cells at four different places in a very lengthy formula. Also, OP asked for a _VBA function_. With my solution, you only enter it once. Plus, there's quite a performance penalty to have the same equation entered multiple times (and thus being interpreted each time it's used). As for your own solution, it matches `ABCD` with `CGA`, for example...

Comment: now now Floris, you know you wouldn't type it more than once then copy down for 5 rows ... FWIW I do prefer your VBA solution to mine as mine seems to have a bug. However, to my mind a solution that avoids VBA and makes use of Excel built-in functionality will always trump a macro, no matter how complex the formula or how succinct the vba code

Comment: You still have to put the reference in FOUR different places in the formula - that's before copying it...: =IF((ISNA(SUM(MATCH(MID(**B1**,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(**B1**))),1),MID(**A1**,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(**A1**))),1),0)))+ISNA(SUM(MATCH(MID(**A1**,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(**A1**))),1),MID(**B1**,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(**B1**))),1),0))))>1,"No Match","Match") . Whether a formula is "always better" is a matter of taste. I like VBA better... And your bug is that you don't `Exit For` when you find a non-match.

Answer (score 0):

I missread the post!

Use function `EXACT`

> Compares two text strings and returns TRUE if they are exactly the
>   same, FALSE otherwise. EXACT is case-sensitive but ignores formatting
>   differences.

I usually add the function UPPER ie:

```
A1 = Some Place
B1 = some place
```

with

```
=EXACT(UPPER(A1),UPPER(B1)) = EXACT(SOME PLACE, SOME PLACE) = TRUE
```

Without UPPER

```
=EXACT(A1,B1) = EXACT(Some Place, some place) = FALSE
```