# string comparison using Regular Expression

Tags: regex

over on the Excel VBA forum [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365250/compare-strings-in-excel-vba) someone has asked for help with matching strings like the below:

```
Examples:
ACBD,AC - Match
ACBD,CA - Match
ACBD,ADB - Match
AC,ABCD - Match
ABC, ABD - No Match
```

the rule is that strings match on condition that all of the letters in one string is contained in the other (i.e either one of the two strings contain all the letters of the other)

So it occurred to me that a Regular expression might be the answer, but I am an absolute newbie on that so can you help please?

Is it possible to match both strtings against each other ?

thanks
Philip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Regex would certainly make the check easier, I don't that this is not possible without additional coding.  You would need the code to do one of the following things:

1) match each character individually then see if all matches were true,
2) re-arrange the order of the characters in all possible order permutations and check each order to see if that matched

Either way, you would need to manipulate the "checking" string in order to cover all of the possible requirements of the match.

If you had asked for "any of these characters" or "all of these characters, in this order", you might be able to do it without extra logic, but since you need "any of these characters, in any order", you've need to manipulate the inputs.

Comment: ok thanks... I thought there might be some mad patter matching logic out there!

Comment: Interestingly, since it is such a "forgiving" rule, you might think that it would be easy, but standalone Regex actually does better with strict rules than it does with relaxed ones.   :)

Comment: so unfair, I was going to use the genius's over here to look like a genius over there... guess I'll have to help the hard way instead!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got an answer for you in VBA but can tell you the steps you need to take.

For each element create a variable with the characters sorted into alphabetical order - you will need to search the net for a sort function to do this as there is not one built into VBA.

Insert a .* between each character in both variables - these are your regexs. You probably want to incorporate this step in with the sort function.

Then all you need to do is match element one of your array with the regex variable created from the second element and then do the second with the first.

Comment: looks like VBA is the way to go then!